# Remove entire time machine backup on external drive

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, time-machine

I recently acquired a macbook pro with Leopard installed. All other software had been removed before I purchased it. I wanted to install Snow Leopard. The advice I received was to be safe I should backup up the current system before installing. I did so and then installed snow leopard.

I am now going to migrate files from an older powermac G5 and any software that might be usable on Mavericks. The Time Machine back up is no longer needed. I would like to get rid of the entire backup on the external drive and start over.

Would simply reformatting the external drive partition solve the problem or is something else necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, reformatting is all you need.